# Office 365 tenants using the same Email Domain Name

Tags: microsoft-dfo365

It seems like impossible but we have 2x companies with @abc.com and @xzy.com as their respective email domain names in separate O365 tenancy.  Is it possible to add a common email domain name for staff of both companies called @pqr.com such that:

1) amy in abc company has email address amy@abc.com and amy@pqr.com
2) tom in xyz company has email address tom@xyz.com and tom@pqr.com

An outsider can send email to amy@pqr.com and still reach her mailbox at @abc.com O365 tenant.
Likewise, the same for tom.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm... are these verified domains in Office 365? That seems an impossibility.

Comment: Either ABC or XYZ has to take responsibility of forwarding PQR mail to the other, and maintain a list of those addresses.

Comment: "... are these verified domains in Office 365?" Yes

Comment: Esa, I was thinking about setting the MX record of pqr.com to a mail server which is able to browse the AD of abc.com and xyz.com and then forward the email accordingly.

Comment: I'm confused. To my knowledge you cannot verify a domain in two different Office 365 tenants. How did you manage to verify the domains?

Comment: @joeqwerty, to acheive what I want, i was meant to say that an external mail server (non-O365) linked to "@pqr.com" will need to read in the email and check the recipient email address against both DC of abc.com and xyz.com to decide which O365 tenat to route to.  Hope it makes sense.